# Comparing two strings using known algorithms

Tags: java, string, algorithm, compare

I'm trying to compare two strings (product names) using some of well known algorithms like [**Levenstein distance**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) and library of different solutions for [string simmetrics](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simmetrics/) (got best results with **SmithWatermanGotoh** alg).

Two strings are:

> iPhone 3gs 32 GB black
>
> Apple iPhone 3 gs 16GB black

Levenstein is working pretty bad on whole string if some words are in different order (which is expected from how algorithm works) so I tried to implement word by word comparison.

The problem I'm facing with is the way to detect similar 'words' that are divided with space char ('**3gs**'->'**3 gs**' ; '**32 GB**'->'**16GB**').

My code compares shorter (word count, if == then str.length) string with longer one. Words are split into `ArrayList<String>`. I'm combining each word from str1 with others in the same string creating new arraylist.

Here is a rough code:

```
foreach(str1)

    foreach(str2)
        res1 = getLevensteinDist
    endforeach

    foreach(combinedstr2)
        res1 = getLevensteinDist
    endforeach      

    return getHigherPercent(res1, res2)

 endforeach
```

This works if the words in str2 are split, but I can't figure out how to do a reverse, detect words in str2 that are split in str1.

I hope I'm at least a bit clear what I'm trying to do. Every help is appreciated.

Comment: No I am not clear what you are trying yo do here.What is your expected out put?

Comment: Difference between two strings (in this case words) in percentage. Basically, I want to return '3 gs' and '3gs' (and reverse) as 100% accurate.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should preprocess your strings, I mean you should remove "a, the, as, an" and all common verbs, numnbers,... from input strings, also you should convert every plural form to the singular form, .... to unify all words. Then you can apply some string matching algorithms, or just put the words into the hashmap, or if they are a lot, put them into the trie, and run your similarity algorithm.

Comment: Hello Saeed, thank you on your response. I think that's not particularly important for the things I want to do. Yes, I admit it would give a better results, but they are not very common in product names so I don't need to take care of it. The problem with my example are the white spaces that split some words so I can't analyze them individually as I get smaller precentage. I want to get 100% if '3 gs' is compared to '3gs'.

Comment: You can get 100% for 3gs vs 3 gs by my approach (because you are going to eliminate numbers), but you will get also 100% for 16gs vs 3gs, by using my method, but if you want to get better result you can combine my method with your current method, but you can not get 100% for 3gs vs 3 gs and perfect result in other combinations except you have an if : if (str1=="3gs" and str2 == "3 gs") return 100%!

Comment: I can't eliminate that part of data because it is essential for the end result. 3 gs vs 4 gs is a big difference product-wise. That's what I want to achieve. But when I compare 3gs with 3 gs I'm getting return percentage lower by even 20-30% (in this particular case). Idea is to find similar products in database based on their product name. That's why I'm comparing two strings as someone can write "Apple iPhone 3 GS 16GB black color" and others can write "iPhone 3GS black" and to return 100% for second string. That's why I went word by word comparison, but the spaces are messing my results.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at TF-IDF. It is specifically designed to compute similarities between textual features.

http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/tf-idf-weighting-1.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to split one of the string into words and then for eash word run SmithWaterman and use scores from SmithWaterman as similarity measure.

Answer (score 0):

13 years ago I wrote my own implementation of trigram fuzzy search algorithm, 
named "Wilbur-Khovayko algorithm".

You can download here: http://olegh.cc.st/wilbur-khovayko.tar.gz

It search "N closest terms" for entered search term.

List of terms - in the file termlist.txt
N - in the variable lim, file findtest.c

Alrorithm very quick: on the old Sun 200mHz, it search 100 closest term among 100,000 
entries for ~0.3 secs.

Comment: 8/25/13-8/27/13 my server was offline (hdd crashed). Please, download again.